# JIRA Issue created after 5pm of yesterday but before 5pm of today

Tags: jira, jql

I can't figure out how to create this filter. All issues created after 5pm of yesterday but before 5pm of today.

I'm trying this but it's not working probably because I'm wrong:
created >= endOfDay(-7h) AND created <= startOfDay(17h)

Answer (score 3):

You mixed up endOfDay and startOfDay. The query below should work for you.

```
created >= startOfDay(-7h) AND created <= startOfDay(17h) ORDER BY created ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. The query works well. Your reply should be marked as Answer.